If $f'' + f = 0$ and $f(0) = f'(0) = 0$, then $f = 0$.
Let $f \in D^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ verifying $f''+f = 0$. Prove that if $f(0) = f'(0) = 0$, then $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Also, show that in any case $f(x) = f(0)\cos x + f'(0)\sin x$.
My attempt:
Let $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $g(x) = (f(x))^{2}+(f'(x))^{2}$. Then $g \in D(\mathbb{R})$ and
$$
g'(x) = 2f(x)f'(x) + 2f'(x)f''(x)\\
      = 2f'(x)(f(x)+f''(x))\\
      = 0,
$$
for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Therefore $g$ is constant, so there exists some $c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $g(x) = c$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. In particular,
$$
c = g(0) = (f(0))^{2}+(f'(0))^{2} = 0.
$$
Thus,
$$
(f(x))^{2}+(f'(x))^{2} = 0,\ \text{for all}\ x \in \mathbb{R}.
$$
And this implies that
$$
f(x) = 0
$$
for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Now suppose that $f(0) = b$ and $f'(0) = a$ for some $a,\ b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f'' + f = 0$. Consider $h:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $h(x) = f(x) - a \sin x - b \cos x$. Then
$$
h'(x) = f'(x) - a \cos x + b \sin x,\\
h''(x) = f''(x) + a \sin x + b \cos x.
$$
Hence,
$$
h(x) + h''(x) = 0
$$
for every $x$. Moreover,
$$
h(0) = f(0) - a \sin 0 - b \cos 0 = b-b = 0,\ h'(0) = f'(0) - a \cos 0 + b \sin 0 = a-a = 0.
$$
So, by the previous result $h = 0$, which says that
$$
f(x) = a \sin x + b \cos x = f'(0) \sin x + f(0) \cos x
$$
for all $x \in \mathbb{R}.$
I´m not 100% sure if I can make the assumption that $f(0) =b,\ f'(0) = a$

It’s not an assumption; you’re simply choosing to call the number $f(0)$ by the name $b$, and $f’(0)$ by $a$. It’s just notation.

Your proof is fine and I must say you have done a great job if you came up with the proof yourself. I learnt this proof from Spivak's Calculus.

Just use the Cauchy–Lipschitz theorem. You have existence and uniqueness of the solution. And $f=0$ is of course a solution.

I’ve never heard about that theorem. This is from a calculus course and I haven’t taken differential equations yet.
